# error! - Cannot bind to the new display member

Tags: vb.net

Help! I am trying to fill a listbox with items from my database with the sql statement, I'm unsure how to fix this error as it keeps coming up. My database only contains two dates, but I need it to be expandable in future, hence the database to store dates.

```
Public ds As New DataSet 
Public con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection 'used to connect to the database
Public provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
Public datafile As String = "Resources/database.accdb" 'database location and version
Public da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Public sqlstatement As String


ds.Clear()
    con.ConnectionString = connString
    con.Open()
    sqlstatement = "SELECT ShowDate FROM AvailableDates"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstatement, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Dates")

    lbxDates.DisplayMember = "ShowDate"
    lbxDates.DataSource = ds
    lbxDates.ValueMember = "ShowDate"
    con.Close()
```

The error  'Cannot bind to the new display member' occurs on the

```
lbxDates.ValueMember = "ShowDate"   line
```

Comment: way you use my answer in your code and you don't mark the answer how soled your issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187867/error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object#37187867

Comment: Im sorry, how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You must affect the dataSource first :

```
  lbxDates.DataSource = ds.tables("Dates")
  lbxDates.DisplayMember = "ShowDate"
    lbxDates.ValueMember = "ShowDate"
```